# Can Vim interpret terminal color escape codes?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, terminal

Many CLI programs output nicely-highlighted text. While most of them check if the output is going to a file, some include the terminal escape codes. I like the output with the escape codes, but viewing these files in Vim is painful.

Can Vim interpret these escape codes into the expected colors? If not, can Vim be set to ignore these escape codes?

Comment: You can also find solution in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/how-to-make-vim-display-colors-as-indicated-by-color-codes)

Answer (score 48):

There are various plugins which allow you to view ANSI colours through escape codes:

- [AnsiEsc.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) – `:AnsiEsc`.
- [Colorizer](https://github.com/chrisbra/Colorizer) – `:ColorToggle`.

---

If you want to *remove* all escape codes, you could use:

```
:%s/<1b>\[[0-9;]*m//g
```

Note: `<1b>` is *not* literal text, it is the escape character, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd> to insert it (it may also show up as `^[`, depending on your `display` setting).

Or you can remove them with `sed`; for example:

```
$ sed 's|\x1b\[[;0-9]*m||g' somefile | vi -
```

Comment: You can also use `\e` in vim's regular expressions and vimscript strings instead of typing `<C-v><Esc>`.

Comment: Colorizer failed to parse a 4400-line file with `'redrawtime' exceeded, syntax highlighting disabled`

Answer (score 13):

If you have a sufficiently modern vim that has the +terminal feature, you can do `:term cat somefile` and you'll get a buffer with all the terminal codes interpreted.

This might work better on large files than e.g. Colorizer, which made my vim unusably slow when I let it loose on a 6000-line file.

Comment: Note: Terminal buffers are by default unmodifiable, and any modification will make the colours disappear.

Answer (score 7):

Building on the previous answer, with this bash function you can open vim and the required file will be displayed with colours instead of codes in a new window "a little bit later" (depending on the size of $1).

```
ansivim ()                               
{                                        
    vim -c ":term ++hidden ++open cat $1"
}
```

- `++hidden` runs the command wihout any open viewport (i.e. window) on it, and
- `++open` will open a window on the buffer only when "the job terminates" i.e. when the `cat` command has finished printing the file.

In summary this effectively makes the window with the file content open only when `cat` has returned in order to have Vim start directly instead of lagging when `cat`-ting large files.

e.g.

```
ansivim build.log
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: drkicknrush, is there a way to do this with stdin?   I'm not sure what is going on, and I can only get it to work with actual files. thx!

Comment: hi @marinara, that is something I wanted as well :-) but I could not get it to work, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to view the file with terminal escape sequences and not edit it, there is [vimpager](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager) (uses AnsiEsc internally). I also have developed a rewrite: [nvimpager](https://github.com/lucc/nvimpager).