# Shell coloring handling with :read command

Tags: external-command

How can I deal with the colored outputs of shell commands when inputing them with `:read`?

As an example, I have a self-defined `git log` command, and I would like to see it in a split window. That works well enough using

```
:new | read !git log-command
```

Unfortunately, the command outputs has some colours. And thus the result looks like

> - ^[[33mac74ef4^[[m 2018-10-22 [me, N] - some text

I guess I could just use as `:substitute` command to clean it up afterwards, or maybe pipe it through `sed`.

But I wanted to know if there was a better way to handle it?

As a minimum, I would like to remove those `^[[m` characters. But even better would be to recognise them and adapt it to color the buffer accordingly.

Comment: [Can Vim interpret terminal color escape codes?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/485/51) may be useful

Comment: Specifically for `git`, you can disable colours, [which is what I do](https://github.com/Carpetsmoker/dotfiles/blob/9b6b7b8/git/gitconfig#L9-L13). Can also use `git --no-color`. I would also expect `git` to automatically disable colours when outputting to something without stdin btw

Comment: If there is no way to disable the generation of the Ansi escape sequences from your command (using e.g. a command line switch, usually `--color=auto` just works), you can strip it by post processing the output, e.g. `:r! git log |sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g"`

Comment: I might have an older oversion of git running, but --no-color is not recognised. I actually tried that. So `sed` and `:substitute` are the best options. Well the other page mentions some plugins, I might give them a try.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to avoid the output of these [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Some commands to this automatically when the output is not to a terminal, others have a command-line argument, e.g. `--no-color` or `--color=never` (even moderately outdated Git versions understand this). Some also react to the terminal type, so prepending `TERM=dumb git ...` might work, too (it does for me).

Alternatively, you can strip off the codes, e.g. with `sed`:

```
git ... | sed 's#\x1b\[[0-9;]*[mK]##g'
```

You can do the same inside Vim, too:

```
%substitute#\e\[[0-9;]*[mK]##g
```

Finally, there are plugins which translate (but not remove) the ANSI escape codes to Vim colors (via syntax highlighting and concealing of the sequences):

- [AnsiEsc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) via `:AnsiEsc`
- [Colorizer](https://github.com/chrisbra/Colorizer) via `:ColorToggle`