# Replace escape sequence `^[` carat left square bracket

Tags: replace

Have text file with contents like:

```
^[[31morigin/some-branch^[[m
^[[31morigin/some-other-branch^[[m
```

These `^[` sequences are highlighted and treated as one character as they are ascii escape sequence. How do I use regex/replace on them?

For example I can do `:%s/origin/potato/g` to replace all `origin` with `potato`, but how do I replace the escaped sequence?

I tried [`:%s/<1b>\[[0-9;]*m//g`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/486/12635) but it gave `E486: Pattern not found: <1b>\[[0-9;]*m`

Comment: You should also be able to accomplish this by using `:h i_CTRL-V`. For instance, you can demonstrate by  typing `/^V^[` where that means these three keys: slash, Ctrl-V, Escape. Then hit Enter and you'll now hop from one instance of embedded Escape characters in your text to the next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\%x1b` to match the ESC character in a pattern:

```
:%s/\%x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g
```

The [`\%x` sequence](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25x) allows you to match a character by its hexadecimal code, which is `1b` in the case of the ESC character, which is usually rendered as `^[`.

By the way, you can use the [`ga` command](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#ga) with the cursor on top of a character to be able to tell its ASCII code or Unicode code point in hexadecimal, decimal, octal, which should help determine which code you should use to match it in a pattern.