# Colorizing log buffer with ANSI color codes

Tags: neovim, color

I have an issue with a log output in a buffer, that i get from Flutter / Dart via [akinsho/flutter-tools.nvim](https://github.com/akinsho/flutter-tools.nvim). The log contains some ANSI color codes, see below. I believe the actual color code is the `[38;5;12m` and `[0m` on each line, but correct me if I'm wrong.

```
D/VRI[MainActivity]( 3255): Cancelling draw. cancelDueToPreDrawListener=true cancelDueToSync=false
I/flutter ( 3255): [38;5;12mProvider<NotificationService> Created - value: Instance of 'NotificationService'[0m
I/flutter ( 3255): [38;5;12mBaseNotificationService | onAppStarted - [0m
I/flutter ( 3255): [38;5;12mProvider<FirebaseMessagingRepository> Created - value: Instance of 'FirebaseMessagingRepository'[0m
I/flutter ( 3255): [38;5;12mProvider<RemoteConfigService> Updated - Value: Instance of 'RemoteConfigService'[0m
D/VRI[MainActivity]( 3255): Cancelling draw. cancelDueToPreDrawListener=true cancelDueToSync=false
I/flutter ( 3255): [38;5;12msharedLocalizationsProvider Created - value: Instance of 'SharedLocalizationsSv'[0m
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the lines to have the correct colors, and I have tried a few different plugins, such as [norcalli/nvim-colorizer.lua](https://github.com/norcalli/nvim-colorizer.lua), [chrisbra/Colorizer](https://github.com/chrisbra/Colorizer) and [MTDL9/vim-log-highlighting](https://github.com/MTDL9/vim-log-highlighting).

But I can't get any of them to do what I want. The first two doesn't work at all (the color doesn't change). Neither automatically, nor by running the command that is supposed to colorize the current buffer. And the third plugin does work, but it doesn't colorize based on ANSI codes.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I just can't figure out what. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my config, if that is of interest: https://github.com/Hannnes1/nvim-config

Update:
I tried the `AnsiEsc.vim` plugin ([from here](https://github.com/powerman/vim-plugin-AnsiEsc)), and that almost works. It removed all the escape codes from the Flutter log, but didn't change any colors.
However, when I tried it in the sample in `:h AnsiEsc`, it colors some codes, like `[30;5mblack[m` , but not `[30;48;5;22m/  \[m`. Not sure what the reason for that is.

Update 2:
I can get the colors to work if I disable 24-bit color (reset `termguicolors` to false). So I would need to find a way to make ANSI escape sequences work with 24-bit colors, I think?

Comment: Log output sounds like a case for `less -R` - unless you need to be able to edit the log, of course.

Comment: I don't need to edit the log, so less -R might work. Are you able to tell how I might do that? It seems like (and forgive me if I use the wrong terminology), the log is just a buffer named __FLUTTER_DEV_LOG__, and not a file or anything.

Comment: There should be some similar questions floating around here; maybe one of those answers your question?

Comment: (You can write the buffer to a file, if you need.)

Comment: Alright, thanks! I will look around

Comment: I took a look at the plugin you're using and it seems to sell based on the point that it integrates Flutter development. Using an external tool like `less` breaks this integration. It seems my suggestion wasn't all thought through. Based on the screenshots in their Readme, colorization is supposed to just work. I'd reach out to the plugin developers and ask them for a fix.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/485/10604

Answer (score 0):

I believe your example lack the `^[` aka Esc character obtained by hitting <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.

With these character inserted I have the following result:

[image]

For the following text:

```
I/flutter ( 3255): ^[[38;5;12msharedLocalizationsProvider Created - value: Instance of 'SharedLocalizationsSv'^[[0m
D/VRI[MainActivity]( 3255): Cancelling draw. cancelDueToPreDrawListener=true cancelDueToSync=false
I/flutter ( 3255): ^[[38;5;12mProvider<NotificationService> Created - value: Instance of 'NotificationService'^[[0m
I/flutter ( 3255): ^[[38;5;12mBaseNotificationService | onAppStarted - ^[[0m
I/flutter ( 3255): ^[[38;5;12mProvider<FirebaseMessagingRepository> Created - value: Instance of 'FirebaseMessagingRepository'^[[0m
I/flutter ( 3255): ^[[38;5;12mProvider<RemoteConfigService> Updated - Value: Instance of 'RemoteConfigService'^[[0m
D/VRI[MainActivity]( 3255): Cancelling draw. cancelDueToPreDrawListener=true cancelDueToSync=false
I/flutter ( 3255): ^[[38;5;12msharedLocalizationsProvider Created - value: Instance of 'SharedLocalizationsSv'^[[0m
^[[30;48;5;22mBlack on Green^[[m
```

Where `^[` again are the Esc character obtained by hitting <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Remark: I inserted them in your text by running:

```
:%s/\[\d\+/^[&/g
```

Where `^[` is obtained by hitting <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> :-)

Comment: Does this still work when you `:set termguicolors` as OP wrote in his *update 2*? To me, it seems the original problem was not the escapes or the plugin but ANSI escapes with `termguicolors`.

Comment: On gVim it works whatever the value of `termguicolors` on Vim and nvim it is indeed only working is off (`:set notermguicolors`) and it seems that on nvim-qt it doesn't work whatever the value of `termguicolors`.

Comment: Thanks, you confirm what OP writes. Based on `:help termguicolors` I would not assume it to have any effect in a GUI version. Now the question remains: can we have `termguicolors` and ANSI color escapes or are they mutually exclusive? I don't know and I'd be in favor of setting `notermguicolors` (the default).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and for confirming that `:set termguicolors` doesn't work. I just noticed that the correct escape codes were removed when I posted. It is actually correct in nvim. I might just look for an alternative to the plugin instead.